# i have the following error while running ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

hosts: all
become: yes
tasks:

- name: build docker image
  command: docker build -t docker-image .
  args:
  chdir: /opt/docker
- name: tag docker image
  command: docker tag docker-image tsvarma07/image:docker-image
- name: push image into docker hub
  command: docker push tsvarma07/image:docker-image
- name: remove docker images from local host
  command: docker rmi docker-image tsvarma07/image:docker-image
  ignore_error: yes

ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <type 'bool'>

The error appears to be in '/opt/docker/pus-image.yml': line 16, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: remove docker images from local host
  ^ here

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. `ignore_error` should be `ignore_errors` per the [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#id3):

```yaml
- name: remove docker images from local host
  command: docker rmi docker-image tsvarma07/image:docker-image
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: No problem! Please mark this as the answer for the question to close